# Drawing a simple Line in user controls

Tags: .net, vb.net, user-controls, drawing, gdi+

I guess my question is very simple but I did not find any answer.

I have a vb.Net project with a MainForm and a Button(`btn1`) and a UserControl(`uc1`).

All I want is when I click on btn1 a simple line draw on `uc1` using `graphics` class.
thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a method in your UserControl to draw the line:

```
Public Class MyUserControl
    Public Sub DrawLine()
        Using g As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, New Point(10, 10), New Point(100, 50))
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then call this from your button click:

```
Private Sub Button26_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button26.Click
    MyUserControl1.DrawLine()
End Sub
```

This is a simple solution, but you may want to [do all your drawing in the paint event of the usercontrol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint.aspx)

Comment: You are welcome - Don't forget to upvote answer(s) and/or accept an appropriate answer (when you can)